# Better way to read the values from JSONObject

Tags: java, json, performance

Please tell the better way to read the value from `JSONObject`:

```
// #1
String offerSubCategory = offeringJson.getJSONObject("offeringSubCategory").getString("code");  
// #2
String offerSubCategory = offeringJson.getJSONObject(Constants.offeringSubCategory).getString(Constants.code);
```

I need to read from `JSONObject` could you please suggest which one is better.

Comment: There is no better way in here, it's a matter of taste to use a `Constants` class or not, you could also use some regular constants in current class

Comment: I would use the 2nd one.. Easier to refactor if you can keep the keys consistent through out the project

Comment: There is their any performace issue using below one  ??                                                       StringofferSubCategory=offeringJson.getJSONObject("offeringSubCategor").getString("code");

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON parsing code is nicely modularized in a single Java file than option #1 might provide a shorter code with slightly better readability.

But, if this code is scattered all over your app than, by all means, go with option #2. Otherwise any data scheme refactoring might be a nightmare;)

**Performance**. It really doesn’t matter. The  Java compiler will (very!) likely *inline* the constants in option #2, resulting in the same bytecode as #1.

**Multiple values**. If you are really planning to read *multiple* values from a same `JSONObject`, I would suggest you breakup your code like this:

```
JSONObject json = offeringJson.getJSONObject("offeringSubCategory");
String xxx = json.getString("xxx");
String yyy = json.getString("yyy");  
...
```

Comment: Ok. But my Question is  "xxx " this value reading from multiple classes that case  which one  is better  String xxx = json.getString(Constant.xxx); (or) String xxx = json.getString("xxx").        class Constants {     public static final String xxx="xxx" }

Comment: @Narasimha As I said in my answer, if you are calling `getString` from multiple classes than using option #2 might be a safer route ;)

Comment: Hey man, if this answered your question be sure to upvote/mark as the accepted answer (click the checkmark). Thanks!